# What does fs stands for in the configuration of wildfly <fs-exploded>?

Tags: configuration, jboss, wildfly

I am interested. What does the abbreviation `fs` mean in the JBoss configuration of exploded war?

I know what this configuration stands for. It is interesting for me to understand what the `fs` means.

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="foo" runtime-name="baz.war">
        <fs-exploded path="D:\my\big\path\to\war"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs` is the abbreviation for **F**ile**S**ystem.

Check [wildfly's xsd](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/d0d8f59ad2e4faa77f9cb51323e55b9040b01136/server/src/main/resources/schema/wildfly-config_4_0.xsd#L2792)

> ```
> <xs:complexType name="fs-explodedType">
>     <xs:annotation>
>         <xs:documentation>Exploded content found on the filesystem</xs:documentation>
>     </xs:annotation>
>     <xs:complexContent>
>         <xs:extension base="fs-baseType"/>
>     </xs:complexContent>
> </xs:complexType>
> ```